# Change Text size according to screen programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I would like to ask

Now I have lots of textviews adjusted and styled correctly the problem is when screen size changes the textviews either become too big or too small

I have tried making different layout files but It does not work though

I used SP and still text overlaps the screen when switching from a device to another

I have made over than 10 layout files for different screens and still I cannot control over it

The question is :

Is there a way to change text size logically instead of having to create alternative layouts or dimens files ??

Here is an example of my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="org.ultradroid.metaldetectorfree.welcome1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/metal"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:textColor="@color/aqua"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/WelcomeTextDescription"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/aqua"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/aqua" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to adjust the text size automatically or same text size on all screen sizes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello guys I found the answer

This awesome library will help everyone do it https://github.com/intuit/sdp

No need for many dimens or many layouts you just need this

Answer (score 2):

You can use autosizing for TextView

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="200dp"
  app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

This will automatically adjust the text size according to your screen width

for more details read  [android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html#setting-textview-autosize)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is you are defining a `static text size` for all the text views use `dimens.xml` for different screen sizes and assign the **values** of the `dimen` to the `textViews` like in the below image

I would suggest you to have a look at [Dimenfy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify) plugin and also at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) link.

[image]

Comment: First of all I said I have more than a different layout and what I did is having the layout with the specific text according to the screen it is in

Comment: May I ask what is the v24 and v21 in your layout and the sw600dp and sw720dp

Comment: As the only thing I did was large-hdpi , large-xxhdpi , large-xxxhdpi and did the same with normal and also made small

Comment: so `sw600dp` is 7 inch tablet screen and `sw720dp` is 10 inch , and `v24 , v21` are android api level's

Comment: have you check the `Dimenfy` plugin

Comment: and its difficult to make all the layouts in the world , but its easy to make dimens and just use as your sizes or text sizes

Comment: Please link to Dimenfy and well is there a logic way to do it that makes the system do the calculations instead of me having to create million of dimens files

Comment: @AmirEmad please read the answer atleast for once , it has the link for `dimenfy` and yes that plugin does this exactly , you will define the ratio once and next tine with only one click these resources will be done

Comment: Well there is no hyper link working at all by the way but thank you for helping ,

Comment: well that's weired , https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify

Comment: that's dimenfy , its the great plugin for this work hope this solves your problem